# Guidance on Specialized bike models

Tags: hybrid-bike, off-road, trails

is the specialized Tricross or Crosstrail bike preferable for a combination of light trail riding and road riding

Comment: Are you asking which of the two is more suited to the task than the other? It's hard to read your question.

Comment: This question is a bit too opinion based for the Stack Exchange format, and isn't useful for archival as your bike selection is highly specific to you. You should go to your LBS and try the bikes and use them to help assess your needs.

Comment: go with the tricross.  this is my personal opinion. it's more aggressive. especially if you plan to ride more on the street.  i've ridden both. one is like a road bike with hydraulic brakes and all terrain tires and the the other (crosstrail) is more of a mountain bike; for people who are off road more than on.

Comment: Question definitely too specialized for this site - I suggest trying your local MTB forum.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your riding style.

If you feel that riding on trails is too jarring to your wrists and don't like drop bars, then go for the crosstrail. It's a hybrid, it's kind of part way to mountain bike, but not really suited to agressive offroad riding.  On this bike you'll be more upright than on a road bike, You're in a less agressive postion for road riding, so this is a better bike for around town, and hopping on your local rail-trail which might be a little bumpy. This bike has a shock, that will suck some power out of your pedaling on the road but make it marginally more comfortable on a trail. This bike also comes with fatter tires than the tricross, which you might like if you're off the roads more than on them.

If you primarily will ride roads, especially if you hang out with folks who want to do longer road rides, then the tricross might be for you.  It is much more like a road bike, with clearance for larger tires and lacking suspension. If you primarily ride roads, and take some other rides on multi-use trails, dirt roads and such which are relatively smooth most of the time, then this will be fine. The slimmer tires that come stock are good all-around tires and work ok on road and trail. However, if you're doing more road riding, you may want to consider getting slick tires for the street.

Both bikes are nice, but you need to consider how you'll primarily use the bike. Neither of these bikes is going to work well on mountain bike singletrack trails, but I don't really think that's what you're asking about anyway.